# OCaml - Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive

Tags: ocaml

Hello i have this program working just fine but giving me a warning that i want to get rid off

```
  let rec replace_helper (x::xs) n acc =
    if n = 0 then
      List.rev acc @ symbol :: xs
    else
      replace_helper xs (pred n) (x :: acc)
    in
    replace_helper tape position []
  ;;
```

this is the warning

```
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:[]
```

What can i do to get rid of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x::xs` pattern can only match a non-empty list (and you forgot to handle the case of the empty list `[]`). Please complete the following code

```
let rec replace_helper li n acc = match li with
   [] -> (*code something here*) failwith "incomplete"
 | x::xs ->
   if n = 0 then
     List.rev acc @ symbol :: xs
   else
      replace_helper xs (pred n) (x :: acc)
   in
   replace_helper tape position []
 ;;
```

and of course read more http://ocaml.org/

Comment: Maybe a note that `x::xs` assumes the argument is a list with at least one element will also be useful to a new user, and hence the empty list must be handled separately.